# Accessing Parameters in SolidJS Router

Tags: solid-js

I am trying to rewrite a project I made in React in Solid. I am trying to use the Solid Router as the documentation advises.

Here are my components so far.
`index.js`

```js
import { render } from 'solid-js/web'
import { Router } from '@solidjs/router'

import './index.css'
import App from './App'

render(
  () => (
    <Router>
      <App />
    </Router>
  ),
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

`App.jsx`

```js
import Articles from './components/Articles'
import Header from './components/Header'
import styles from './App.module.css'
import Navbar from './components/Navbar'
import Topics from './components/Topics'

function App() {
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <Header />
      <Navbar />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Articles />} />
        <Route path="/:topic" component={<Topics />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

`Navbar.jsx`

```js
import { onMount, createSignal, For } from 'solid-js'
import { NavLink } from '@solidjs/router'
import { getTopics } from '../utils/api'

const Navbar = () => {
  const [topics, setTopics] = createSignal([])

  onMount(() => {
    getTopics().then(({ topics }) => {
      setTopics(topics)
    })
  })

  return (
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <For each={topics()}>
          {topic => (
            <li>
              <NavLink href={`/${topic.slug}`}>{topic.slug}</NavLink>
            </li>
          )}
        </For>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  )
}

export default Navbar
```

The problem I think seems to be in the component below
`Topics.jsx`

```js
// Get the params from the url
import { useParams } from '@solidjs/router'
import { createSignal, For, onMount, createResource } from 'solid-js'
import { getTopicArticles } from '../utils/api'


const Topics = () => {
  const { topic } = useParams()
  console.log(topic)

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{topic}</h1>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Topics
```

The params seem to be `undefined` no matter what. I understand that Solid router is not exactly the same as React-Router but for this simple example I can't see where I am going wrong.

The desired outcome is to be able to click on the `NavLink` in the `Navbar.jsx` component and that routes to the desired path, for example `http://localhost:3000/cooking` and render the topic I need, but the params are always undefined.

This is the result of the api call, `api/articles?topic=undefined`
The desired result is to attach the param at the end of the api with useParams, just like in my `React` version

Edit: below is the `Topics.jsx` component updated to a working version, not sure if it is the best way.

```js
import { createSignal, For, createEffect } from 'solid-js'
import { useParams } from '@solidjs/router'
import { getTopicArticles } from '../utils/api'
import Article from './Article'

const Topics = () => {
  const params = useParams()

  const [articles, setArticles] = createSignal([])
  const [loading, setLoading] = createSignal(true)

  createEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true)
    getTopicArticles(params.topic).then(({ articles }) => {
      setArticles(articles)
      setLoading(false)
    })
  })

  return (
    <>
      {loading() && <div>Loading...</div>}
      <h2>{params.topic}</h2>
      <For each={articles()}>{article => <Article article={article} />}</For>
    </>
  )
}

export default Topics
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could be related to the object returned from `useParams` is being reactive. `console.log` returns an empty object but destructing outputs the values as expected. That is because of the proxy and totally normal.

> Retrieves a reactive, store-like object containing the current route path parameters as defined in the Route.
> https://github.com/solidjs/solid-router#useparams

Also regular query parameters like `?id=1&name=John` does not work with `useParams`, for those use `useSearchParams`.

```js
import { render } from "solid-js/web";
import {
  Router,
  useParams,
  useSearchParams,
  Route,
  Routes,
  Link
} from "@solidjs/router";

const Home = () => {
  const [params, setParams] = useSearchParams();
  console.log({ ...params });
  return <div>Home</div>;
};

const Blog = () => {
  const params = useParams();
  console.log({ ...params });
  return <div>Blog {JSON.stringify(params)}</div>;
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link href="/?id=1&name=john">Home</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link href="/blog/js/1">Blog</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route path="/blog/:category/:id" element={Blog} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
};

render(App, document.getElementById("app")!);
```

Check https://codesandbox.io/s/solid-router-demo-forked-71ef9x?file=/index.tsx for live demo.

Also, we pass component name to the component prop like so:

```js
<Route path="/" component={Home} />
```

Comment: I have tried the example you have shown, in the console I get `{}[[Prototype]]: Object ` with nothing inside and just empty {} on the page. I will link to my repo for you to see what I am trying to achieve in more detail. 
Solid version https://github.com/BullDogPatch/NC-NEWS-but-with-SolidJS/
React finished version https://github.com/BullDogPatch/FE-NC-NEWS-PROJECT

Also I had already tried the createResourse

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/solid-router-demo-forked-71ef9x?file=/index.tsx @trombonee See it works.

Comment: @trombonee Are you using Solid Playground? If so, that is normal because Playground lacks solid router module.

Comment: No I am using Vscode, I have just looked at the codesandbox you linked, I have copied that to vscode and that example works.
But for some reason in the usecase I am trying to do the params are always undefined

Comment: I am a little bit closer, I am now getting the params. I did this `    <Route path="/:topic" component={Topics } />` instead of this `    <Route path="/:topic" component={<Topics />} />` like you said.  Still not able to render to page yet, but console log is giving me object of what I need.

Comment: @trombonee Using regular query parameters like `/blog?id=1` does not work with useParams. I updated the answer.

Comment: I now have it rendering the pages I need, big thanks to you, I am also going to upvote your answer as what you was saying was exactly what I needed to do. I just read it wrong.
I ended up having to use a `createEffect`  as that automatically tracks behaviour.
I am going to update my question to show what I have now. I have not figured the `createResource` out. If you feel there is a better way to do it please let me know and thank you so much. Solid is a joy to have fun with

Comment: Yes, createResource is the way to get data asynchronously from the server. Also, if you are using query params from the url like ?id=1, use the setter function returned from useSearhParams rather than creating a signal and tracking the value manually. The code inside the edited section is problematic. No need to wrap a resource into an effect. Use onMount if you need.

Comment: unfortunatly for some reason using `createResource` or useSearchParams` I can't get to work in my case. It's sort of a diffrenent way to the way you think in React.